# PHP Registration script using prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli

I have got the following registration code, it SEEMS to be working but it isn't actually inserting the entered information into my table. It all runs with no errors showing up, and the "echo 'end';" is displaying.

**Edit, updated code:**
Now get this error

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type
>   definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\test.php on line 19

Which is this line:

```
$insert_stmt->bind_param($email, $password, $random_salt, $user);
```

PHP:

```
   <?php
include "includes/db_connect.php";

if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    //Default user perms
    $perms = "user";

    $password = hash('sha512', $_POST['p']); //Need to add JavaScript to hash password before it gets here
    //Create random salt
    $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, getrandmax()), true));

    //Create salted password
    $password = hash('sha512', $password.$random_salt);

    //Add insert to database script
    //Use prepared statements!
    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, password, salt, perms) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
        $insert_stmt->bind_param($email, $password, $random_salt, $perms);
        $insert_stmt->execute();
    }
    echo "Email: ".$email."<br />";
    echo "Password: ".$password."<br />";
    echo "Random Salt: ".$random_salt."<br />";
    echo "Permissions: ".$perms."<br />";
}
?>
```

This is my db_connect.php page

```
<?php
define("HOST", 'localhost');
define("USER", 'ppa_user');
define("PASSWORD", 'password');
define("DATABASE", 'ppa');

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    //No database found, redirect to setup
    $url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/ppa/setup.php';
    header('Location: '.$url);
}
?>
```

Comment: Your query is preparing the sql statement for `4` columns on the `users` table, however, you are binding `5` params. That doesn't seem right. remove `'ssss'` before `$_POST['email']`

Comment: Where do you see 5 params, or am I missing something? @LatheesanKanes

Comment: By the way, I'm pretty sure you don't need to hash the password with javascript. Also, check this out. https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm There's a great php solution all written out.

Comment: @Fred-ii- apologies; you're right - there are 4 params being prepared, binding `5` params (so the last value will be offset). I think the problem is with his if statement - out of scope. @Martyn - can you try my answer below?

Comment: No problemo. And I think you may be right about how the condition is set. @LatheesanKanes

Comment: @m59 i'm following a guide: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Comment: The problem now, seems to be that `$user` is not defined. Try using `bind_param($email, $password, $random_salt, $perms);`

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that, that should be $email. Corrected it but still getting the same error.

Comment: But you already have `$email`

Comment: Ok so now try `$insert_stmt->bind_param("ssss", $email, $password, $random_salt, $perms);`

Comment: @MartynLeeBall Are you suggesting that just because you followed a guide that your implementation is secure? The link I gave you is an accepted standard for hashing that is far more secure than what you're doing. Read the information on that page.

Comment: Did you also check if your columns are indeed named `email - password - salt - perms` ? I'm baffled. And check to see if your form inputs are named as per variables.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It now works with: 'bind_param("ssss", $email, $password, $random_salt, $perms)'. m59 - I'm reading that link now, very interesting, I will have a look into it thanks.

Comment: Great news, glad to hear it works @MartynLeeBall

Comment: @Fred-ii- Can you put that in an answer so I can accept it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, it's a good idea to close the question as it is now answered. And you're welcome, cheers.

Comment: It's been posted below http://stackoverflow.com/a/19961815/1415724

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to close this question as being answered, have come to the conclusion the OP needed to use the following code:

```
$insert_stmt->bind_param("ssss", $email, $password, $random_salt, $perms);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following:

```
//Add insert to database script
    //Use prepared statements!
    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, password, salt, perms) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"));
    $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $_POST['email'], $password, $random_salt, $user);

//Execute the prepared query
$insert_stmt->execute();
echo "end";
```

with:

```
//Add insert to database script
//Use prepared statements!
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, password, salt, perms) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
    $insert_stmt->bind_param($_POST['email'], $password, $random_salt, $user);
    $insert_stmt->execute();
    echo "end";
}
```

Comment: Getting this error now: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\test.php on line 19

Comment: Sorry i forgot to remove `ssss` from my answer. post updated, try that now.

Comment: No you did remove it, I have removed it as well but it still doesn't work, get the error I posted above.

Comment: Then try to define your `$_POST['email']` as `$email` as in `$email=$_POST['email'];` then use `$insert_stmt->bind_param($email, $password, $random_salt, $user);` I think it's the parentheses playing some funny tricks with the `$_POST`. @MartynLeeBall

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, password, salt, perms) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"));
$insert_stmt->execute(array($_POST['email'], $password, $random_salt, $user));
```

Comment: Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\test.php on line 19

Comment: use this if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, password, salt, perms) VALUES (:email, :pass, :salt, :perms)"));
$insert_stmt->execute(array(':email' =>$_POST['email'], ':pass' => $password, ':salt' => $random_salt, ':perms' =>$user));